# How do generate screen elements dynamically in the OutSystems platform?

Tags: dynamic, user-interface, outsystems

I am using the OutSystems platform and I am having trouble implementing something like a dynamic questionnaire. Admin users should be able to login and add new questions(no limit to number of questions), modify existing questions/answers and delete existing questions. Answer Choices can be of various types like radio buttons, dropdowns, text boxes etc. Normal users should see the updated questionnaire upon next login.

I was thinking of creating something like a template to which we can add dynamic controls at runtime. We can use dynamic page rendering features in .net etc to implement this, but we are looking to see how I can implement this in OutSystems as here we add most of the controls as static controls. The major hurdle is that the number of web blocks that we need to create is not fixed. It may depend on a user selection.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have a List Records widget with several If widgets inside to display the appropriate "controls". I believe this is one way to have dynamic controls. I don't know if this applies to your specific problem.